# Compare attributes of parent and child class in Python

Tags: python, oop

I have a Python class like this:

```
class A:
  __val1: float = 0.0
  __val2: float

  def __init__():
     validate()

  def validate() -> bool:
     if not hasattr(self, __val2): # how is this supposed to be done?
         raise NotImplementedError()
     return self.__val1 >= self.val2
```

My goal is to use `A` as an abstract class where the child classes are forced to implement `__val2`.

I create a child class `B`:

```
class B(A):
  __val2 = 1.0
  
  def __init__():
     super().__init__()
```

When I initialize an object of class `B`, this error is thrown:

```
E   AttributeError: 'B' object has no attribute '_A__val2'
```

I tried modifying `B`  like this:

```
class B(A):
  A.__val2 = 1.0
  [...]
```

But this throws the same exception.

Trying the same but with `super`:

```
class B(A):
  super.__val2 = 1.0
  [...]
```

But this throws another error:

```
E   TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'super'
```

What is the Pythonic way do handle this kind of abstraction?
How should `validate()` be implemented so that it checks for `__val2`?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/what-is-the-meaning-of-single-and-double-underscore-before-an-object-name

Comment: Not sure what your are suggesting. Renaming `__val2` to `val2` in all places does not make a difference. Neither does using the notation `_A__val2` (unless I misunderstand where you suggest to apply it).

Comment: You have an incorrectly defined class. `self` is not defined anywhere, and you appear to be confusing class attributes with instance attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use double preceding underscores for your class attribute names, python converts them to `_<classname>_<varname>`. So in your case, `A.__val2` becomes `A._A__val2` and `B.__val2` becomes `B._B__val2`, which means they won't share the same name. See the link Thierry Lathuille has shared in the comment on your question, and here's the link to python docs: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables.

You can fix this by not using double underscores, so go for something like `_val2` or `val2`.

There are a few other issues in your code: all your class methods need `self` as the first argument, and you need to access them by calling `self.<method_name>`. So to access `validate`, you need to call it with `self.validate()`. Also, the second arg to `hasattr` must be a string.

Here's an updated example that should fix your issue:

```
class A:
  _val1: float = 0.0
  _val2: float

  def __init__(self):
     self.validate()

  def validate(self) -> bool:
     if not hasattr(self, '_val2'):
         raise NotImplementedError()
     return self._val1 >= self._val2

class B(A):
  _val2 = 1.0

  def __init__(self):
     super().__init__()

print(B()._val2)
```